# how to convert a html to jpg with same quality

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a card that is made by HTML and some data comes from the database by query now I have to convert that particular div into png or jpg with good and same quality like HTML. html to canvas is not the good option for that.

As Image quality is blur

Answer (score 0):

you can use pdfcrowd API library for it.  https://pdfcrowd.com/doc/api/html-to-image/php/

or you can do it with Html to Jpeg with Php and html2canvas

https://github.com/erayakartuna/html-to-jpeg-php

Thanks

Comment: I tried that already but image quality was not good so I am looking for a good option.